# Javascript, CSS optimizer

Tags: javascript, python, css, optimization

Are there any analogues for [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) or [Juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer/), but written on Python?

Answer (score 1):

django-compressor is a django app that I think does what Jammit.

http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

webassets - Asset management for Python web development.

http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/